# Can I reuse the buffer in open_memstream

Tags: c, stream, posix, stdio

When working in a loop, I'd like to re-use the already allocated buffer multiple times:

```c
char *membuf = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
while(1) {
    FILE *f = open_memstream(&membuf, &size);

    uint8_t iobuf[8192];
    int32_t readbytes = 0;

    // some I/O here
    while(readbytes = read(/*some I/O params here*/) != 0) {
        fwrite(iobuf, sizeof(uint8_t), readbytes, f); 
    }

    fclose(f);

    // process message, once done, loop for next message
    // explicitly NO free of membuf!
}
```

Is this possible? Or will this lead to UB?

Comment: Dynamically allocating memory and throwing it away without freeing will lead to *memory leak*. If you do that for too long time, the program may crash due to lack of memory. In worse case, instead of just crashing the single application, the system may do too much swapping and the whole system may slow down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this with `open_memstream`, but doing so won't lead to UB, but rather a memory leak. [`man 3 open_memstream`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) says "The function dynamically allocates the buffer" and "After closing the stream, the caller should [free(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) this buffer." Your code as written will overwrite `membuf` each iteration of the loop with a new allocation, preventing you from ever freeing the old ones. It won't reuse the old allocation, as you seemed to hope it would.